# UnknownAttributeError on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i1:-form-based-workflow) on how to create a Ruby-on-Rails blogging website with comments and tags, and have put my work so far on https://github.com/khpeek/jumpstart-blogger/.

The problem is that when I try to create a new article with tags as shown below,

[image]

I get an error message "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ArticlesController#create" (see below).

[image]

However, according to the tutorial I should at this point expect the article to "go through". The `articles_controller.rb` has a 'set' method for `tag_list`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  include ArticlesHelper
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.article_id = @article_id
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def tag_list=(tags_string)
  end

  def create
    # fail
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' created."
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    flash.notice = "Artice '#{@article.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(article_params)
    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' updated."
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

end
```

Further, the "to_s" method for the "Tag" class has been modified to return its name:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :articles, through: :taggings

    def to_s
        name
    end
end
```

In short, I don't understand why `tag_list` is not recognized as an attribute for `Article`. How might I fix this?

Comment: You need to add it add it as a database column on Article - use a migration. Your   `def tag_list=(tags_string)` method in the controller doesn't seem like it's doing anything, and should probably be in the Article model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In you `article.rb` add:

```
def tag_list=(tags_string)
  # first split the tags based on "," which is coming from the form
  tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
  # search if any particular tag is present or not, based on that assign them
  new_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
  self.tags = new_tags
end
```

Also, in **articlesController.rb** add:

```
def article_params
 params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list)
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And you can also delete the empty `def tag_list=(tags_string)` in `ArticlesController` in the question. The `tag_list=` defined for `Article` in `article.rb` is the only version that will be called by `Article.new(article_params)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It seems the key point to make it 'go through' is to include `def tag_list=(tags_string)` (instead of only `def tag_list`) in the method definition in `article.rb`. I deleted the empty method in `ArticlesController` as Rory O'Kane suggested and didn't have to include the `def article_params` (at least, not to get rid of the error).

Comment: Correction: the `def article_params` code given by Emu is necessary, but was already included in the `ArticlesHelper` module (which I hadn't listed).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Rails 4. Have you included tag_list into your Strong parameter permit list?